# guidance on using ejb 3 with Datasource connection and lots of methods

Tags: jdbc, ejb-3.0

I have to code an Stateless EJB3  that uses callable statements, and builds a XML structure.
I'm getting a DataSource Connection from JNDI;

```
ctx.lookup('DS').getConnection();
```

my ejb has lots of methods(that build each part of the XML), and i found it is cumbersome to pass the connection as a parameter to every method that i could call.

the thing is:

Should I put the connection as a field in my ejb, open it on @PostConstruct and close it only on @PreRemove? so that it would use the same connection OPEN for the entire lifetime of the bean.

or

Should I use an Interceptor with a try/cacth block that opens the connection and asign it to the bean on every call? Moreover wouldn't this cause concurrency problems? given the connection is a field and is shared by the threads calling the stateless bean methods?

I think I want the same thing we can do with JPA:

```
@PersistenceContext EntityManager em;

public String businessMethod(String param){
    em.find(...);
    someMethod(param);
}

private void sometMethod(String param){
    em.createQuery...;
}
```

but with java.sql.Connection

thanks in advance

Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid passing connection as parameter to all methods, you can try field-based injection for the data-source.

```
@Resource(name="defaultDS")
    private javax.sql.DataSource defaultDS;
```

Then you can have the data-source available in all the methods present in that bean & can get connection from it.

Comment: ok, but if my business method call two private methods that both call _defaultDS.getConnection()_, they will have the same connection ?

Comment: They will probably have different connections.

Comment: I only need to do select queries, so no problem if it is a different connection. Thankyou very much Nayan!

Comment: If the connections are shareable methods are in the same transaction, you should be fine.